# PSExec could not start Regedit.exe on remote PC

Tags: psexec, regedit

Background:
I have several registry keys that are saved and used to update/configure remote PCs in my environment. I may not have deployed the device, previously, but I use these registry keys to update the PC as I fix/repair/etc...I am part of a team of 45 managing about 25,000 workstations and peripherals in our region of the enterprise.

if I use this command from my Win 10 PC to a Win 7 PC, it executes without problems.

psexec \remotecomputer -u domain\adminaccount regedit.exe /i /s "\server\share\directory1\directory2\directory3\someregistry.reg"

psexec starts regedit, imports the above registry file and closes.

If I run that exact same command from my Win 10 PC to another Win 10 PC, I get the following error, from CMD as ADMIN,

"PsExec could not start regedit.exe on REMOTEPC_HOSTNAME:
The system cannot find the file specified."
**it can't find regedit??? WTF??**

I'm curious why Win 10 is blocking me, as an admin, from importing a registry key?

I've tried reg import as a solution, but I keep getting syntax errors and it can't find the file/pathway.

It's almost like the remote PC, doesn't recognize admin input due to UAC settings?

In testing, I've set the group policy editor to enable remote registry tools, no change. I've enabled remote registry services and set to start the service automatically. I can access the PC registry via remote registry...but psexec just won't work on the remote device.

I can RDP to the device and run the command line equivalent:
regedit.exe /i /s "\UNC\pathway...\etc*.*reg" it executes, without issues. 
**this proves that regedit is working**

Can anyone provide some expertise on this?

Answer (score 1):

add -s flag to psexec to run regedit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The old *PsExec* trick of running RegEdit doesn't always work. This is because *psexec* depend on a hidden SMB Administrator service. (Which in any security sense should be disabled.)

> PsExec allows redirects of the input and output of a remotely started
>   executable through the use of **`SMB`** and the hidden $ADMIN share on the
>   remote system. With this share, PsExec uses the Windows Service
>   control Manager API to start the PsExecsvc service on the remote
>   system which creates a named pipe that PsExec communicates with. This
>   named pipe is what allows for input/output redirection back to the
>   system that launched PsExec.

So instead, in order to remove any *TrustedInstaller* owned registry Keys, you can use a different tool. This worked:

- **[`ExecTI`](https://winaero.com/download.php?view.1991)** - *Run as TrustedInstaller*
  Run it to open the *ExecTI* GUI and enter: `C:\Windows\regedit.exe`

Comment: It's best not to answer off-topic questions. Instead, if you downvote them and vote to close then eventually the site will automatically delete them if they haven't got any answers.